# Probability mass function of product of two binomial variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two i.i.d. binomial variables X and Y with given n and p. What is probability mass function of product of X and Y?

Comment: @Math1000 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427815/probability-mass-function-of-product-of-two-binomial-variables

Comment: @Math1000 No, in that formula you'd have $P(XY = n^2) = 0$ since ${n \choose n^2} = 0$.  It is $\sum_{i,j: ij = k} P(X = i) P(Y = j)$.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt if there is a simple expression.  To get started $P(XY=0)=P(X)=0+P(Y)=0-P(X=0)P(Y=0)$, $P(XY=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)$, $P(XY=2)=P(X=1)P(Y=2)+P(X=2)P(Y=1)$.  The general term for$P(XY=k)$ then depends on the factoring of $k$.

Comment: Specifically, it's $\sum_{ij = k} {n \choose i} p^i (1 - p)^{n-i} {n \choose j} p^j (1 - p)^{n-j}$. I'm not aware of anything particularly nice that can be said about this.

Comment: The answer is here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427815/probability-mass-function-of-product-of-two-binomial-variables